# written whole javascrpit code but add to cart function is not working and no error is being shown

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am working with Django. Below is my JavaScript code, in this code, "hello world" is getting printed in console but when I am clicking *add to cart*, then "clicked" is not getting printed.

```
console.log("Hello world");
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart');
for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var action = this.dataset.action;
        console.log('clicked');
    });
}
```

This is part of my HTML code containing the button:

```html
<div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        {% for i in product %}
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{i.desc}}</p>
                    <button data-product="pr{{i.id}}" data-actions="add"
                            class="btn btn-primary add-btn update-cart">
                        Add to Cart
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% block js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

No errors are getting printed when running this. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a django issue. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and add a [mcve] with only HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Comment: And where is this script relative to the HTML? Have you tried `console.log(updateBtns);` right before the `for` loop, maybe it's an empty array.

Comment: One thing that I can see is that in your html is `data-actions` and in your javascript is `dataset.action`, It lacks of `s` but I dont think so thats the issue right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to do this

You missed an s on actions too

Delegate from the nearest static container, then you do not need to loop at all

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (e.target.classList.contains('update-cart')) {
      const action = tgt.dataset.actions;
      const product = tgt.dataset.product;
      const title = tgt.closest(".card-body").querySelector(".card-title").innerText;
      // or
      const desc = tgt.previousElementSibling.innerText;
      console.log(action, product, title, desc );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
  <div class="carousel-item active">

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Product 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Description 1</p>
          <button data-product="pr1" data-actions="add" class="btn btn-primary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Product 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Description 2</p>
          <button data-product="pr2" data-actions="add" class="btn btn-primary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item"></div>
  </div>
```